# Scheduled Task or Timer Class

Tags: asp.net, iis, timer, scheduled-tasks

Speaking of server resources (in general) and background processes. Would it be better to use a separate executable and a windows scheduled task or use the timer class and make use of the same resources as you application.

There are a few pros and cons to both methods, but what I'm wondering is this: Would making use of shared resources (thread pools and the like) be better than separate resources? Sure the process would be taking resources from the app, but isn't it technically already doing that either way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have given too little context to really understand the whole. how does the timer trigger the activity at certain time if the application is closed or there is nobody connected (logged on)? This kind of stays the same for both ASP.NET and Windows client because IIS takes the application down when nobody is connected for a while.

in my opinion a Windows' scheduled task is way better because you decouple from IIS application pool / application lifecycle and you also separate better and are sure that at that time the call will be executed and the activity started.

Comment: good point about the application pool lifecycle. that reason alone is probably enough to drive me in the other direction.